# Get dynamically generated (rendered) HTMl from IE

Tags: html, browser, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Is there an easy way to get rendered HTML from IE 11? I can not use WebBrowser control because my web application needs to install ActiveX control prior to loading Javascript generated HTML - which is not possible with WebBrowser control.

Thanks in advance :)
Harit

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your question fully, but you could try to use AJAX and post the generated content to a server page

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Do I need some kind of server setup in order to do that?

Comment: What is it that you have at the moment, and what do you need? Are you generating some HTML with JS and trying to save it to somewhere? If so, where are you trying to save it to? What process is doing the "rendering", and what process needs to do the "getting"?

Comment: Let me try to explain the problem in a bit different way. I have a HTML page which has some inline scripts - which dynamically generate some more controls and merge with the HTML. In other words, the rendered HTML is a combination of static and dynamic (generated through Javascript) HTML pieces. When I use 'View Source' or get HTML from F12, I see the static HTML along with the scripts (not the dynamically generated HTML). I was wondering if there is a way to get the combined HTML?

Comment: So, this doesn't need to be an automated process, you just need to get it by hand? If so, I'm pretty sure you just need to look in the right place in the F12 tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using internet explorer 9 but the process should be the same or very similar for ie 11:

- Navigate to the webpage
- Press F12 to launch developer tools (Also available from the tools menu)
- Right click the opening HTML tag
- Select copy outerHTML

You should now have all the dynamic HTML in your clipboard to paste where you like

Comment: I have tried that. For some reason, that only copies the HTML tag and not the inner HTML contents.

Comment: @HaritSingh That will happen if you click copy, but copyOuterHTML copies the entire page